# Scroll ListBox to top selection

Tags: asp.net, listbox, scroll, multi-select

Is there any way to programmatically scroll down a multiselect `ListBox` to show the top selection? Using ASP.NET here.

**UPDATE** (to clarify):
There's a form with a multiselect `ListBox` with a lot of items (country list), so not all of them are visible at the same time. The user makes one or several selections and saves the form. Later, the user goes back to edit it, and I want to automatically scroll the `ListBox` as to show the first selection the user made. For example, if the user selected Portugal, I want the `ListBox` to scroll so that the user sees it on the screen straight away, and doesn't need to manually scroll down to it.